# Is Qt classified as a c++ library? If not a library, how would you classify QT?

Tags: c++, qt, cross-platform, language-design

I recently started looking into Qt (I installed Qt 4.5.2 and installed their Eclipse-CDT plugin called "qt integration v1.5.2" and I will do all my development in Linux-Eclipse-CDT-QTintegration).

Originally I thought Qt was a straight vanilla C++ library but when I installed and started running Qt example code I saw lots of "weird" things that I consider to be non-standard.

My goal is to understand at a high level of abstraction:

- **Is Qt classified as a C++ library?**
- **If not a library, how would you classify Qt (analogy/metaphors are appreciated)?**

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Qt is a framework, not a library.  This isn't a hard-and-fast distinction enforced by the programming language, rather, it describes how the code is designed and intended to be used:

A **library** is someone else's code that is used by your code.  Using a library means that your application remains as it is, it just has another library to help it out.

A **framework** is someone else's code that your code fits into.  Using a framework means that the framework defines the structure of your application.

If you're using a framework, you need to learn that framework's conventions, which may be a bit different than the base language; otherwise, you can spend a lot of time fighting the framework, and you'll be missing out on some of what it has to offer.

Qt in particular doesn't look like straight vanilla C++ because it isn't straight vanilla C++.  It adds (limited) extensions to C++'s object system to permit features like signals and slots; these extensions are implemented using Qt's moc, which acts as a C++ preprocessor.  For more information on Qt's extensions to C++:

- [Meta-Object System](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/metaobjects.html)
- [Why Doesn't Qt Use Templates for Signals and Slots?](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/templates.html)

Comment: No QT is not a framework. There is no inversion of control flow other then GUI typical event handling. QT is a language extending library.

Comment: I agree with @Lothar, lets say I create Android app with Qt "framework". My app will be `.so` library and it will  be included in template android project. So my whole Qt app fits into Android framework, and in my app is using someone else code(Qt library). So is this correct?

Answer (score 4):

Qt is a set of C++ libraries along with a preprocessor and part of a build system.

Comment: +1 Also can be considered a "development platform", meaning you can build your whole app from the libraries Qt provides.

Answer (score 4):

Most gui frameworks/libraries add to the language, just because C++ doesn't (or didn't until very recently) natively support the kind of events you need for a gui.

Qt chooses to do this with extentions to the language and a pre-compiler, MFC and wxWidgets do this with c macros and the c-preprocessor. 
The Qt approach means it can do more (it's not limited by the cpp macro language) at the expense of a slightly more complicated build environment.